# HTML/CSS collage of images neatly fitting into a rectangle

Tags: html, css

I am in the progress of making a collage of images that fit perfectly into a rectangle, so far I have managed to create the top layer for it. However the last row has got me confused as I can't seem to get them into place using CSS. (You may need to run it through your browser to see it clearly)

```js
  var container = document.querySelector('#grid');
  var masonry = new Masonry(container, {
    columnWidth: 1346,
    itemSelector: '.grid-item'
  });
```

```css
.grid-item {
  float: left;
  border: 0px solid transparent;
}
.grid-item--width146x100 {
  width: 125px;
  height: 100px;
  float: right
}
.grid-item--width146x300 {
  width: 125px;
  height: 300px;
  float: right
}
.grid-item--width200x100 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px
}
.grid-item--width200x200 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px
}
.grid-item--width300 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px
}
.grid-item--width500x200 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px
}
.grid-item--width500x400 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px
}
.grid-item--width200x200(1) {
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px
}
.grid-item--width200x100(1) {
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width300">
    <img src="http://s30.postimg.org/njfrtgaoh/300x200.png" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width200x100">
    <img src="http://s11.postimg.org/v0d12pcyr/200x100_2.png" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width500x400">
    <img src="http://s22.postimg.org/s8jfeeiep/500x400.png" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width200x200(1)">
    <img src="http://s22.postimg.org/uxiti6d9t/200x200_2.png" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width146x100">
    <img src="http://s13.postimg.org/463k9fm8j/146x100.png" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width200x100(1)">
    <img src="http://s14.postimg.org/prasnic9d/200x100.png" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width500x200">
    <img src="http://s30.postimg.org/hz3aitbtd/500x200.png" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width200x200">
    <img src="http://s8.postimg.org/56vmkw3kl/200x200.png" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width146x300">
    <img src="http://s23.postimg.org/670g2cmaz/146x300.png" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the desired effect and how does it differ from the example?

Comment: you need to use masonary layout kindly refer http://masonry.desandro.com/ this plugin looks good

Comment: I am wanting it to fit into a perfect rectangle. But some of the shapes aren't floating to the top the are just sticking to the bottom

Comment: @RRR If you read the question you could see he's using Masonry

Comment: Please post all of the code necessary to recreate your issue, at least in a jsfiddle or jsbin. As is you didn't include the Masonry layout so your preview is completely useless to us

Comment: @ZachSaucier yeah sorry I missed it... Morgan if you want to make a collage which fits into a rectangle choose image dimensions which fits into rectangle and however if you resize the browser window or view that on a mobile the divs will shift to accommodate screen size and the shape changes

Comment: The images I chose do fit into it I calculated them.

Answer (score 0):

`Div` dimensions should in ratio to fit into each other neatly.

Here the dimensions your have mentioned are not in ratio.

```
.grid-item--width146x100 {
  width: 125px;
  height: 100px;
  float: right
}
.grid-item--width146x300 {
  width: 125px;
  height: 300px;
  float: right
}
.grid-item--width200x100 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px
}
.grid-item--width200x200 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px
}
.grid-item--width300 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px
}
.grid-item--width500x200 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px
}
.grid-item--width500x400 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px
}
```

So correct them and keep them in ratio, for eg.

```
.grid-item-1 {
      width: 150px;
      height: 200px
    }

.grid-item-2 {
      width: 300px;
      height: 400px
    }

.grid-item-3 {
      width: 75px;
      height: 100px
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: By doing that it just messes it all up look https://jsfiddle.net/midwackcan/hvuw32h7/

Comment: Do you have any other tips?

Comment: Have a look at this `codepen` `http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/osFxj`, i guess u were missing to add the JS masony library.